# 'end of statement expected' with Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

I have the following class method (in a scrapy spider):

```
class MY_Spider(Spider):

    name = "MY"

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(min_id,max_id,1):
        ....
```

I set min_id and max_id above the class definition (screenshot). However If I change these to:

[image]

The linting says 'end of statement expected' for min_id and for max_id .

Why?

Comment: Post code as text, not as images.

Comment: @Prune, I wanted to show linting..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A zero at the beginning of an integer literal indicates that the literal is written in the octal number system. The only valid digits in the octal system are 0 through 7. 8 is an illegal digit, therefore (and 9, too). Remove the front zeros from your numbers. As a side note, 0170 is not the same as 170: 0170 is actually the octal notation for the decimal 120.

Comment: Didn't realize I was indicating an octal. How would I pad a decimal with '00' In this case? I have to make the input a 5 digit decimal number.

Comment: There is no difference between decimal 170 and 00170, why do you need those zeros?

Comment: I'm scraping a website , and the input has to be a 5 digit number/string starting with a 0.

Comment: Oh. Then you can convert it into a decimal integer by explicitly telling so to the `int()` function: `int('00170',10)`.

Comment: Thank you.very much

Comment: what if I want to just assign 0 to my variable?